# Add statement is not working for sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have written this code for inserting data with Foreign key value but it is not going in Sqlite3_open method . Please help me . I am not getting what is the issue?

```
- (void)AddCashGame {
    sqlite3_stmt *addStmt;

    appDelegate = (XYZAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSString *dbPath = [appDelegate.GetDocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PokerDatabase.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"Db path is %@",dbPath);
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) ){
   const char *sql="insert into CashGameCell (CashLocation,CashGames,CashBank,CashBuy,CashFood,CashNote,CashRebuyCount,CashRebuyTotal,CashTokes,CashPlayer,CashProfileid) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    if (sqlite3_prepare(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Error while creating database %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    }
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [CashLocation UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [CashGames UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [CashBank UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [CashBuy UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 5, [CashFood UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 6, [CashNote UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 7, [CashRebuyCount UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 8, [CashRebuyTotal UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 9, [CashTokes UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 10, [CashPlayer UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 11, CashProfileid);   
    }

if (SQLITE_DONE!= sqlite3_step(addStmt)) {
    NSLog(@"Error while inserting");
}
else Cashid = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
NSLog(@"cash id in profile model %d",Cashid);
sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);
sqlite3_close(database);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I have similar code to add values into a database. Why not try this:

```
- (void)AddCashGame {
sqlite3 *database;
NSString *path =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDictionary, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *database_path=[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PokerDatabase.sqlite"];

const char *dbPath = [database_path UTF8String];

NSLog(@"Db path is %@",dbPath);

sqlite3_stmt *statment;

NSString *q=[NSString stringwithFormat:@"insert into CashGameCell (CashLocation,CashGames,CashBank,CashBuy,CashFood,CashNote,CashRebuyCount,CashRebuyTotal,CashTokes,CashPlayer,CashProfileid) values (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")", value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,value11]; 

const char *query = [q UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &database)==SQLITE_OK ){

  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &statement, nil)== SQLITE_OK) { 

    if(sqlite3_step(statement){
    //I assume this code below is correct         
      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [CashLocation UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [CashGames UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [CashBank UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [CashBuy UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 5, [CashFood UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 6, [CashNote UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 7, [CashRebuyCount UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 8, [CashRebuyTotal UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 9, [CashTokes UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 10, [CashPlayer UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 11, CashProfileid);
    }
  }
  else{
     NSLog(@"Error while creating database %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
  }   
}

sqlite3_close(database);
}
```